# Getting Web content that has javascript using vbscript

Tags: javascript, url, vbscript

Using the following code in my vbscript

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://somesight.com/blah?234", False
o.send

Wscript.Echo o.responseText
```

I am trying to write out data from and external site.  But most the data i want is created from a javascript function with in, and is not accessible this way, because when i run this script it says:

You must have JavaScript enabled.

Is there a way to simulate having Javascript in a vbscript, or perhaps translating the o.responseText with javascript enabled?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Did you mean to get the source code of any web page ?

Comment: @Hackoo: basically, but after the javascript functions that were on the page have ran.  The javascript calls retrieves the data from the server and displays it.  That displayed data is what I am trying to get.  Does that make any since?

Comment: I can get the data if I have a browser. Maybe i need to approach the problem differently, but I like to grab this data and put it in a data sheet.  Also there are different values i can put in, so I need a programmatic solution it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
Option Explicit
Const TriStateTrue = -1 ' Pour la prise en charge de l'Unicode
Dim URL,ie,Titre,objFSO,ws,strFileHTML,strFileTxt,strFileHTMLAscii
Dim objHTMLFile,objTxtFile,strFileTxtAscii,DataHTML,DataTxt
URL = InputBox("Entrez l'URL pour y extraire son Code Source HTML "&vbcr&vbcr&_
"Exemple ""http://www.google.fr""","Extraction du Code Source © Hackoo © 2014",_
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193018/getting-web-content-that-has-javascript-using-vbscript")
If URL = "" Then WScript.Quit
Titre = "Extraction du Code Source de " & URL
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFileHTML = "CodeSourceHTML.txt"
strFileTxt = "CodeSourceTxt.txt"
strFileHTMLAscii = "SourceCodeHTML.txt"
strFileTxtAscii = "SourceCodeTxt.txt"
ie.Navigate(URL)
ie.Visible=false
DO WHILE ie.busy
    wscript.sleep 100
LOOP
'***********************To Get Data in HTML mode****************************
DataHTML = ie.document.documentElement.innerHTML
DataTxt = ie.document.documentElement.innerText
Set objHTMLFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileHTML, 2, True, TriStateTrue)
objHTMLFile.WriteLine(Titre&vbcr&String(120,"*"))
objHTMLFile.WriteLine(DataHTML)
objHTMLFile.Close
'************************To Get Data in Texte mode**************************
Set objTxtFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileTxt, 2, True, TriStateTrue)
objTxtFile.WriteLine(Titre&vbcr&String(120,"*"))
objTxtFile.WriteLine(DataTxt)
objTxtFile.Close
ie.Quit
Set ie=Nothing
Call Convert(strFileTxt,strFileTxtAscii)
objfso.DeleteFile strFileTxt
Call Ouvrir(strFileTxtAscii)
Call Convert(strFileHTML,strFileHTMLAscii)
objfso.DeleteFile strFileHTML
Call Ouvrir(strFileHTMLAscii)
wscript.Quit
'*************************************************************************
Function Ouvrir(File)
    Dim ws
    Set ws=CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.run "Notepad.exe "& File,1,True
end Function
'*************************************************************************
Sub Convert(UnicodeFile,AsciiFile)
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Const ModeAscii = 0, ModeUnicode = -1
    Dim fso, f_in, f_out
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
    Set f_in = fso.OpenTextFile(UnicodeFile, ForReading,, ModeUnicode)
    Set f_out = fso.OpenTextFile(AsciiFile, ForWriting, true, ModeAscii)
    Do Until f_in.AtEndOfStream
        f_out.Write f_in.Read(1)
    Loop
    f_in.Close
    f_out.Close
End Sub
'*************************************************************************
```

Comment: That looks promising.  I will try it this evening, and let you know.  Thanks

Comment: I tried the above script as is, and it comes close to what i want, but for some reason, the data from the javascript function within the code is not being called.  Perhaps there needs to be a pause or wait for any functions on page to finish?

Comment: Actually with:
DO WHILE ie.busy
    wscript.sleep 100
LOOP
it should be waiting long enough.. i wonder why the functions aren't bringing back data.

Comment: Right now im looking into Snoopy and GreaseMonkey to see if either works.  You have any experience with these?